# Creating a new int/char knowing the bits

Tags: java, byte, bit

I'm trying to make a new character/integer. All I know about that char/int is only the first 6 bits. I have a variable called

```
number
```

It's quite a large number and it is formed from 24 bits. With this number I want to make use of the toBinaryString method

```
bits = Integer.toBinaryString(number);
```

So now I have a variable **bits** containing the bits from my variable number. At this moment I want to divide this string into 4 so I am left with 4, 6 characters strings which will represent my bits for my integer/character. How would I go about creating a number or a character knowing these bits?

Just to make sure I explain it in every detail let me give you an example:

I have

```
number = "abc" // 011000010110001001100011 as binary representation
```

Now I want to create a new integer with the first 6 bits (011000). Another integer with the following 6 bits (010110) and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want it as a *string*? It sounds like you really just want bit-shifting operations:

```
number = ...;

int bottomBits = number & 0x3f;
int middleBits = (number >>> 6) & 0x3f;
int upperBits = (number >>> 12) & 0x3f;
```

So `bottomBits` is the *least-significant* 6 bits, then `middleBits`, then `upperBits` (the most-significant bits, so the first 6 bits in your binary string).

Comment: +1 A loop and `long` value may be appropriate. A `long` will give you 10 x 6 bit values.

Comment: Silly question I guess. Amazing answer. Thanks !